# How can I generate in python an array like this?

Tags: python, numpy

I try to figure it out how can I implement a function in python to generate arrays like this (please ignore the fact that is the same number):

```
[[0101111010, 0101111010,0101111010, 0101111010,0101111010,0101111010,0101111010],
[0101111010,0101111010,0101111010,0101111010,0101111010,0101111010,0101111010]]
```

I write this code but I don't know if it's the best idea:

```
import numpy as np
import  random
sol_per_pop = 20
num_genes = 10
pop_size = (sol_per_pop,num_genes)   
population = np.random.randint(2, size=pop_size) 
print(population)
```

I don't want to use string. I want to find the best solution. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask why are you not using strings? I've been in a similar scenario before, where I found strings work alot better but I'm keen to hear your take on this.

Comment: How do you intend the binary number to be generated? Just a random 10-bit number?

Comment: Yes,I want to random generate the binary number

Comment: What do you mean by "best" solution? Your approach is just fine in the sense that the code is quite simple, but it uses lots of memory (64 bits while just one 1 bit is actually needed). More memory efficient would be to treat the values as integers. You can use `np.random.randint(2**num_genes, size=sol_per_pop)` to draw them, and only convert them to string (`bin()`) one value at a time, where you actually need the bits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what this would be useful for. But it might still be fun.

```
import random
int("{:b}".format(random.randint(0,1<<64)))
```

Or:

```
import random
r = random.randint(0,1<<64)
sum(10**i*((r>>i)&1) for i in range(64))
```

Or, if we must use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
significance = 10**np.cumsum(np.ones(64))
np.sum(significance*np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 2, 64))
```

Yet another idea:

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
significance = 10**np.cumsum(np.ones(64))
result = np.zeros(64)
result[nrng.choice(range(64), rng.integers(0, 64))] = 1
np.sum(significance*result)
```

As you can see, there are many approaches to solve the same problem.